# pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: get_throttling_function_name: could not find match for multiple

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytube

I used to download songs the following way:

```
from pytube import YouTube
video = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AWXvSBHB210')
video.streams.get_by_itag(251).download()
```

Since today there is this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 170, in fmt_streams
    extract.apply_signature(stream_manifest, self.vid_info, self.js)
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytube\extract.py", line 409, in apply_signature
    cipher = Cipher(js=js)
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 43, in __init__
    self.throttling_plan = get_throttling_plan(js)
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 387, in get_throttling_plan
    raw_code = get_throttling_function_code(js)
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 293, in get_throttling_function_code
    name = re.escape(get_throttling_function_name(js))
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 278, in get_throttling_function_name
    raise RegexMatchError(
pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: get_throttling_function_name: could not find match for multiple

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Me\Documents\YouTubeDownloader.py", line 3, in <module>
    video.streams.get_by_itag(251).download()
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 285, in streams
    return StreamQuery(self.fmt_streams)
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 177, in fmt_streams
    extract.apply_signature(stream_manifest, self.vid_info, self.js)
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytube\extract.py", line 409, in apply_signature
    cipher = Cipher(js=js)
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 43, in __init__
    self.throttling_plan = get_throttling_plan(js)
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 387, in get_throttling_plan
    raw_code = get_throttling_function_code(js)
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 293, in get_throttling_function_code
    name = re.escape(get_throttling_function_name(js))
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 278, in get_throttling_function_name
    raise RegexMatchError(
pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: get_throttling_function_name: could not find match for multiple
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I was making a youtube video downloader but pytube is giving error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68956373/i-was-making-a-youtube-video-downloader-but-pytube-is-giving-error)

Comment: Try the following one. In my case it worked.

python -m pip install git+https://github.com/kinshuk-h/pytube

Comment: The latest instance of this issue is [here](https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/1281)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had same issue when i was using pytube 11.0.0

so found out that there is a regular expression filter mismatch in pytube library in cipher.py class

```
function_patterns = [

    r'a\.C&&\(b=a\.get\("n"\)\)&&\(b=([^(]+)\(b\),a\.set\("n",b\)\)}};',
]
```

Now there is a update of pytube code yesterday to 11.0.1

```
function_patterns = [

    r'a\.[A-Z]&&\(b=a\.get\("n"\)\)&&\(b=([^(]+)\(b\)',
]
```

With this code update now downloading youtube video with pytube works!!!

Update your pytube library with this command:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pytube
```

Answer (score 36):

Because youtube changed something on its end, and now you have to change pytube's cipher.py's `get_throttling_function_name` variable `function_patterns` to the following

```
r'a\.[a-zA-Z]\s*&&\s*\([a-z]\s*=\s*a\.get\("n"\)\)\s*&&\s*'
r'\([a-z]\s*=\s*([a-zA-Z0-9$]{2,3})(\[\d+\])?\([a-z]\)'
```

And you also have to change line 288 to this:

```
nfunc=re.escape(function_match.group(1))),
```

You'll have to use this workaround until pytube officially releases a fix.

EDIT: This will very likely be broken again in the future as youtube updates their website, make sure to check the github issues for possible solutions

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, not with 11.0 nor with 12.0 :-(

Comment: worked for me, with v12.0.0. Thanks.

Comment: Also worked for me. I'm using version "12.0". Note that the updated "function_patterns" is at line "264" of "cipher.py". Thanks!

Comment: Not working anymore. Is there a new regex?

Comment: Works with v12.0, thanks for the fix. Hopefully this is resolved in the next version bump ([Github issue](https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/1293))

Comment: Worked with v12.0. Had a lot of struggle with v11.0 but this fixed worked perfectly.

Comment: @laocius could you describe your exact issue and post it as a separate question instead? Because without information it's hard to know what happened.

Comment: Note the `function_patterns` array to change can be found on 272~273. There are others in the file that should not be modified. Also, the lack of commas is not a typo.

Answer (score 9):

Update your (cipher.py -> get_throttling_function_name -> function_patterns) with this one and then it will work.

```
function_patterns = [
    # https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/29326#issuecomment-865985377
    # https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/commit/48416bc4a8f1d5ff07d5977659cb8ece7640dcd8
    # var Bpa = [iha];
    # ...
    # a.C && (b = a.get("n")) && (b = Bpa[0](b), a.set("n", b),
    # Bpa.length || iha("")) }};
    # In the above case, `iha` is the relevant function name
    r'a\.[a-zA-Z]\s*&&\s*\([a-z]\s*=\s*a\.get\("n"\)\)\s*&&.*?\|\|\s*([a-z]+)',
    r'\([a-z]\s*=\s*([a-zA-Z0-9$]+)(\[\d+\])?\([a-z]\)', ]
```

Comment: This was what worked for me. Some notes: (1) You can find where cypher.py is by entering pip show pytube. (2) There are two function_patterns in cypher.py. Make sure you update the right one!

Answer (score 7):

In Pytube version 15.0.0, you just need to remove  `;` in line 287 of `cipher.py` file.

> Change `r'var {nfunc}\s*=\s*(\[.+?\];)'.format(` to `r'var {nfunc}\s*=\s*(\[.+?\])'.format(`

Answer (score 4):

The updated regex expression:

```
r'a\.[a-zA-Z]\s*&&\s*\([a-z]\s*=\s*a\.get\("n"\)\)\s*&&\s*'

r'\([a-z]\s*=\s*([a-zA-Z0-9$]{2,3})(\[\d+\])?\([a-z]\)'
```

in the answer above may be parsed incorrectly by pycharm if just copy/pasted from web.  To fix, try merging the two strings onto one line:

```
r'a\.[a-zA-Z]\s*&&\s*\([a-z]\s*=\s*a\.get\("n"\)\)\s*&&\s*\([a-z]\s*=\s*([a-zA-Z0-9$]{2,3})(\[\d+\])?\([a-z]\)'
```

I found this fixed the problem for V12.0.0

Answer (score 3):

You can use yt-dlp: https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp

```
!pip install -U yt-dlp
```

Then for your video (mp4 + 1080p) use the following code:

```
!yt-dlp -f "bestvideo[height<=1080][ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/best[ext=mp4]/best" "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AWXvSBHB210"
```

Comment: This saved me in June 2023!

Comment: Me too! Tks for sharing! June 2023!

Comment: Worked ! Jul 2023 !
Mac Python 15.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade pytube

> python3 -m pip install --upgrade pytube

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, that resolved that error - pytube is now giving various other errors, and by adding the following at the lines where the errors occur solved it for me:

Around line 417...

```
if(raw_code == ""):
    return ""
```

Around line 344

```
if(raw_code == ""):
    return []
```

And around 321 change it to:

```
if(match != None):
    code_lines_list = find_object_from_startpoint(js, match.span()[1]).split('\n')
    joined_lines = "".join(code_lines_list)
    # Prepend function definition (e.g. `Dea=function(a)`)
    return match.group(0) + joined_lines
else:
    return ""
```

After this it started working for me.